# What is the purpose of metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets in Hystrix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hystrix

What exactly is the purpose of `metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets` in Hystrix? How will this property affect the way the circuit breaker behaves?

For instance how will the below two configurations differ?

```
metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds 10000
metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets 10
```

vs

```
metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds 1000
metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets 1
```